# docker-compose build fails with no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  auth_api:
    build:
      dockerfile: my-server/dev.Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - '9000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./my-server:/app/
```

And the following `my-server/dev.Dockerfile`

```
FROM golang:1.13.3

WORKDIR /app

RUN ls
# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY ./go.mod ./go.sum ./


# Download all dependencies. Dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source from the current directory to the Working Directory inside the container
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN go build -o main .

# Expose port 8080 to the outside world
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run the executable
CMD ["./main"]
```

Now, when I run

```
docker build my-server/ --file=my-server/dev.Dockerfile
```

The docker container is built successfully.

However, when I run `docker-compose build`,
It fails with the output:

```
Building auth_api
Step 1/9 : FROM golang:1.13.3
 ---> dc7582e06f8e
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c4005150884a
Step 3/9 : RUN ls
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 59051268c382
Step 4/9 : COPY ./go.mod ./go.sum ./
ERROR: Service 'auth_api' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder881802488/go.mod: no such file or directory
```

Any idea how to fix it?

**EDIT**

TBH I'm new to setting up docker-compose etc, so not really sure of how the different config options work. If there is any change I could make to my `docker-compose.yml` which would set the working directory for COPY, that would be best

Comment: Does changing `context: .` to `context: my-server` help?  (Is the Dockerfile `my-server/my-server/dev.Dockerfile`?)  That option matches the path argument to `docker build`.

Comment: @DavidMaze I just checked. In fact, that does the job, along with changing the `dockerfile` parameter to `dev.Dockerfile`. Thanks! Post an answer please, and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `context:` option in the `docker-compose.yml` matches the path option to `docker build`, except that `docker build` seems to strip off a file prefix if it matches the build context directory.  If you're manually running

```sh
docker build my-server/ --file=my-server/dev.Dockerfile
#               ^^^                          ^^^
#             context                     dockerfile
```

then you need to change the `docker-compose.yml` to match

```yaml
build:
  dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
  context: my-server
```

All paths in the `Dockerfile` are relative to the context directory, so given the files you show, this would correspond to a filesystem structure like

```
docker-compose.yml
my-server/
+-- go.mod
+-- go.sum
+-- dev.Dockerfile
```

Comment: I think the structure will be like `my-server/
+-- go.mod
+-- go.sum
+-- dev.Dockerfile`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `docker build` and Docker Compose `build:` options line up exactly.

Comment: @David I don't think your last edit to completely correct. I do run the command `docker build` as mentioned in the question, But when I set the context in `docker-compose.yml`, the `dockerfile` location `docker-compose` picks is relative to the context so I don't need to mention the directory there

Comment: The [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/#text-files) docs also say the `-f` path is relative to the root of the context.

Comment: ...and yet, experimenting, it seems to get stripped.  Wacky.